# unable to parse extra symbol in JAXB

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, jaxb2

[image]

Using JAXB Marshalling and Unmarshalling in java, I am not able parse the symbol which is appearing before the "This end use consumption" text in image.

getting following error.

```
Generic Exception being handled : Fatal error: PCDATA invalid Char value 20 at :11.
```

I want skip this kind of symbols, How I can do that using JAXB.

Please help.

Comment: Can you paste that character in question ?

Comment: Yes it is there, you find it in image before "This end use " text

Answer (score 1):

Your source XML is probably not valid XML. Is it possible the XML is created by concatenating text without taking care of escaping special characters where necessary ?

Comment: Yes, but i do not have any control on text, user can enter any text. So I need to escape it

Comment: @AshwiniSukale - Yes you would need to escape the text the user entered to make it XML friendly.  How are you currently converting that text to XML?

Comment: You can Base64 encode the complete user input string.

Answer (score 0):

The invaldi character is \x14, DC4, a control character. (I wonder, how this can be entered or what SW entity adds it.)

This is the valid range for characters, according to the XML W3C recommendation:

```
#x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
```

This means that all other control characters have to be removed (not escaped!). This can be done by filtering user data with a simple regular expression, e.g.

```
String input = ...;
saneInput = input.replaceAll( "[\\x00-x1F&&[^\\x08\\x0A\\x0D]]+", "" );
```